# javascript object literal methods to populate the objects

Tags: javascript

i have an object like this :

```
var data = {
    scope: "some_scope",
    redirect_urls: {
        return_url: return_url,
        cancel_url: cancel_url
    },
    someotherobj:{
        method: "get"
    },
    setRedirectUrls: function(return_url, cancel_url) {
        this.redirect_urls.return_url = return_url;
        this.redirect_urls.cancel_url = cancel_url;
    }
}
```

and i want to have this object `JSON.strigify`'ed but i miss something or i dont know if this is the right way like :

```
data.setRedirectUrls('http://www...','http://www....');
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

but i get `ReferenceError: "return_url" is not defined.`

Comment: Your object has a function. This is not a valid JSON format

Comment: @Weedoze: That won't cause a "ReferenceError: "return_url" is not defined.". The object should still be stringified, just without the `setRedirectUrl`'s method. 123onetwothree: The exception you're seeing is likely because you haven't got a `return_url` variable declared in scope (referenced in your line 4 in your snippet).

Comment: This is a javascript object. 2. return_url is not defined anywhere

Comment: so then add the function to object prototype ?

Comment: "ReferenceError: "return_url" is not defined." — Well yes, but that has nothing to do with the second chunk of code. You use those variables in the object literal but haven't defined them. Why would you expect any other behaviour? (Well, the second chunk of code *repeats* that mistake, but you never reach it)

Comment: You are declaring `redirect_urls.return_url` and `redirect_urls.cancel_url` with `return_url` and `cancel_url` that don't exists at that moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to instantiate your objects properties with variables which haven't been defined/don't exist, change them to empty strings.

```js
var data = {
  scope: "some_scope",
  redirect_urls: {
    return_url: "",
    cancel_url: ""
  },
  someotherobj: {
    method: "get"
  },
  setRedirectUrls: function(return_url, cancel_url) {
    this.redirect_urls.return_url = return_url;
    this.redirect_urls.cancel_url = cancel_url;
  }
}

data.setRedirectUrls('http://www...', 'http://www....');
var json = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(json)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey Check out my snippet, I added an explanation to my answer there.

```js
var data = {
    scope: "some_scope",
    redirect_urls: {
        return_url: '', //          return_url: return_url; Can't do this here because they don't exist.
        cancel_url: ''  //          cancel_url: cancel_url;
    },
    someotherobj:{
        method: "get"
    }
}

// After you know the structure of your object then add the actions to it here.

data.setRedirectUrls = function(return_url, cancel_url) {
    this.redirect_urls.return_url = return_url;
    this.redirect_urls.cancel_url = cancel_url;
}

data.setRedirectUrls('http://www...','http://www....');
var json = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Adding the function to `data.__proto__` will litterally add it to every object (including functions and arrays and other class instances).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I changed it to just add it to the object.